# Sort an Object by Value

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have a JS Object which contains a list of chats. What i need is to sort them in desc order according to the **last_message_at** value which is an epoch (Unix).

The structre of the Object is as below

```
var test = {
    "138545616542461": {
        "otherUser": {
            "$id": "128636544201178",
            "$priority": null,
            "age": 35
        },
        "last_message_at": 1268482500
    },
    "138545616542460": {
        "otherUser": {
            "$id": "128636544201178",
            "$priority": null,
            "age": 35
        },
        "last_message_at": 1368482500
    }
};
```

Typically, the sorted object should have `1368482500` at the Top. Array can be used for sorting purposes but finally the result should be an Object.

Tried some stackoverflow examples with no luck..

Comment: You are using the wrong type of data structure if you're expecting to sort the keys of an object on the object.  Use an array for sorted order, not a plain object.

Comment: It is not a wrong data type if Object is wanted instead of Array! The program get VERY much faster to find elements with test["138545616542460"] instead of some test.find("138545616542460") looping an array. Complexity come down from O(n) to O(1) !!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of important issues prohibiting the *exact* steps you are trying to accomplish so I've taken the liberty of a quick method that does what I *think* you want -- namely enumerating the keys of the object and sorting by the *numeric* value of `last_message_at`

```
Object.keys(test)
      .sort((a,b) => {
             return test[a].otherUser.last_message_at - test[b].otherUser.last_message_at; })
      .map((elt) => { return test[elt]; });
```

This function returns an array (because it must). As [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) pointed out object property order is never guaranteed in Javascript.

Another point to be made is that you cannot have an object with duplicate keys -- your `test` object supplied will only have one key when the initialization of the object is finished.

Comment: But i'm losing key while doing so

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right -- you can't have an object with duplicate keys.

Comment: But the keys are different.. see the last 1 and 0 end of the key

Answer (score 0):

The order of properties in an object is not guaranteed in Javascript.

Definition of an Object from ECMAScript:

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

You should either use arrays or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects which guarantees key order.